# How to display a number from a register or a var in 8086

Tags: x86-16

how do i print a number from a var or a register?
this is my code so far:
i would like to print the number that is saved in centimeters or AX in the array where is says " = X cm " thanks.

```
;
; XXX.asm - feet inches to centimeters
;
    .MODEL SMALL
    .STACK 100h
    .DATA
InputMessage DB 'Enter height in feed inches (e.g. 6.2):',13,10,'$'
ResultStr DB 13,10,'X Feet X Inch = X cm','$'
Multiply_Word DW 3048
Multiply_Word1 DW 254
Divide_Word DW 100
Divide_Ten_Word DW 10
centimeters DW 0

.CODE
ProgStart:
     MOV AX,@DATA     ; print
     MOV DS,AX
     MOV AH,9
     MOV DX,OFFSET InputMessage
     INT 21h
     MOV AH,1    ; klita
     INT 21h
     MOV ResultStr[2],AL
     SUB AL,'0'
     MOV AH,0
     MUL Multiply_Word
     DIV Divide_Word
     ADD centimeters,AX
     MOV AH,1
     INT 21h
     MOV ResultStr[9],AL
     SUB AL,'0'
     MOV AH,0
     MUL Multiply_Word1
     DIV Divide_Word
     ADD centimeters,AX
     MOV AX,centimeters
     ;;;
     MOV AH,9
     MOV DX,OFFSET ResultStr
     INT 21h
     ;;;
     MOV AH,4Ch
     INT 21h
END ProgStart
```

Comment: You have to print using the ascii values of each character. So if you want to print 31 you should print '3' '1'. To do so you should check the matching ascii value of '3' and '1' . Then:
mov dl, (matching_ascii_value)
mov ah,2
int 21h